# Set Hidden textbox using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs, please see this code in http://jsfiddle.net/6XDeV/

*what I want:*

When click on the button add it will appear `$scope.todotest` value a long with the value in textbox.

*My problem:*

When I add the first it not show the date along with the text in textbox and if I add the second time it will appear. And I want to appear since the first time that click on add button.

Anyone know about this help me to fix please, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AngularJS World!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the $scope variable *todotest* **after** adding a new item to your array *todos*.

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText,test:$scope.todotest, done:false});
  $scope.todoText = '';
  $scope.todotest = '23'; // This should be done before the push
};
```

See updated fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BeCpR/).

Answer (score 2):

That's because at the first time you call `addTodo` the `todotest` is `undefined`.

Just move the `$scope.todotest = '23'` before the `push`, like this:

```
  $scope.addTodo = function() {
     $scope.todotest = '23';
     $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText,test:$scope.todotest, done:false});
     $scope.todoText = '';   
  };
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/757d3/

Answer (score 0):

add this line $scope.todotest = '23'; before this  $scope.addTodo = function() {

check this[code] http://jsfiddle.net/6XDeV/1/[/code]